# How to limit network ranges in Dovecot

Tags: linux, unix, centos, mail-server, dovecot

I want to specify some netrange to access dovecot on my mail server.

I adjusted the

```
login_trusted_networks =
```

parameter in dovecot.conf but it didn't work, I still can access dovecot in some others netranges.

Here is my dovecot configuration

```
/etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf
protocols = imap pop3
listen = *, ::
login_trusted_networks = 192.168.10.0/24 172.18.16.0/24

/etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-auth.conf
disable_plaintext_auth = no
auth_mechanisms = plain login
!include auth-system.conf.ext

/etc/dovecot/conf.d/10-ssl.conf
ssl = no
```

Comment: This is normally done using some firewall software or device.

Comment: @Bodo why is this normally, `login_trusted_network` should to prevent login from another networks, isn't it?

Comment: @kolserdav I'm not sure I understood everything correct. According to https://doc.dovecot.org/settings/core/, `login_trusted_network` is not to prevent login from other networks but to grant specific permissions to clients connecting from trusted networks which is useful for proxies. As I understood the question, the OP wants to prevent any access to dovecot from other networks. Depending on the network the `listen` setting might help, but firewalls are more flexible, and it might be better to have one place to limit access for all network services instead of using per-service settings.